# How to Grouping, Selecting Several Value to be a columns And Select Certain Word in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have A Data like this, or you can see my Notebook here : [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pKAQjOV38A0o211CjCW45DIk9RWywLhh#scrollTo=pV4HijQhRxGK)
or the raw file here : [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gacha321/data_cleaning/main/Help.csv)

| Id | Type | Label | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Introduction | This Project will be created By Mr.X |  |
| 1 | A | Capacity | 100MB |  |
| 1 | A | Speed | 10Km/h |  |
| 1 | A | Weight | 10kg |  |
| 2 | A | Introduction | This-Project-will-be-created-By-Mr.A |  |
| 2 | A | Capacity | 100MB |  |
| 2 | A | Speed | 5km/h |  |
| 2 | A | Weight | 1kg |  |
| 3 | B | Introduction |  | This Project will be created By Mr.C |
| 3 | B | Capacity |  | 100MB |
| 3 | B | Speed |  | 5km/h |
| 3 | B | Weight |  | 1kg |
| 4 | B | Introduction |  | This Project will be created By Mr.D |
| 4 | B | Capacity |  | 100MB |
| 4 | B | Speed |  | 5km/h |
| 4 | B | Weight |  | 1kg |
| 4 | B | Height |  | 1m |
| 4 | B | Color |  | red |

You can see that Type A has label value in `Value` column but the type B has label value in `Value2` Column. I want to grouping for each ID and transposing a `Label` value to be columns like this.

| Id | PJ | Capacity | Speed | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr.X | 100MB | 10Km/h | 10kg |
| 2 | Mr.A | 100MB | 5Km/h | 1kg |
| 3 | Mr.C | 100MB | 5Km/h | 1kg |

Where `PJ` Column is from the Value of `Introduction` But we only get the People Name, and my data also have `-` symbol for several value.

I'm a beginner Using Python and I didn't know how to do. Because I think It's hard if I cleaning the data using excel because there is a lot of data. Thank you

Comment: chk id in your example. B has id 2?

Comment: I'm sorry I have corrected the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `melt` to first reshape the "Value..." columns, then `pivot` using the new "value" column:

```
(df.melt(['Id', 'Type', 'Label'])
   .dropna(subset=['value'])
   .pivot(index=['Id', 'Type'], columns='Label', values='value')
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .dropna(axis=1) # remove incomplete columns
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
   Id Type Capacity                          Introduction   Speed Weight
0   1    A    100MB  This Project will be created By Mr.X  10Km/h   10kg
1   2    A    100MB  This-Project-will-be-created-By-Mr.A   5km/h    1kg
2   3    B    100MB  This Project will be created By Mr.C   5km/h    1kg
```

Comment: Wow that's cool. So the dropna will exlucde the incomplete columns? and How can If I want to select several columns from the 'Label' because at my case it has so many Label and I just want to select several columns only

Comment: Yes it's possible, slice with the desired columns before `reset_index`: `[['col1', 'col2']].reset_index()`.

Comment: I have a problem in this code .pivot(index=['id', 'type'], columns='label', values='value') that shows  ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape :(

Comment: This means you have duplicated combinations among the id/type and future columns. You must either deduplicate or aggregate with `pivot_table`. Give it a try and if needed this should be a new question with all details to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

**First**

fillna `Value` and use `pivot`

```
(df
 .assign(Value=df['Value'].fillna(df['Value2']))
 .pivot('Id', 'Label', 'Value'))
```

output:

```
Label   Capacity    Introduction                            Speed   Weight
Id              
1       100MB       This Project will be created By Mr.X    10Km/h  10kg
2       100MB       This-Project-will-be-created-By-Mr.A    5km/h   1kg
3       100MB       This Project will be created By Mr.C    5km/h   1kg
```

**Next**

make `PJ` column and `reset_index` (full code including **First**)

```
(df
 .assign(Value=df['Value'].fillna(df['Value2']))
 .pivot('Id', 'Label', 'Value')
 .assign(PJ=lambda x: x['Introduction'].str.split('By[ -]').str[1])
 .iloc[:, [-1, 0, 2, 3]].reset_index())
```

output:

```
Label   Id  PJ      Capacity    Speed   Weight
0       1   Mr.X    100MB       10Km/h  10kg
1       2   Mr.A    100MB       5km/h   1kg
2       3   Mr.C    100MB       5km/h   1kg
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The output is what I need. But I have question. Actually the 'Label' Column has so many label, not only Introduction to capacity. How if I want to Select several column in 'label' column?

Comment: I used `iloc` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Comment: I mean, how if I want to select Capacity and Speed only from the label?

Comment: i used `iloc`, if you don know `iloc`,  read link page. This is basic of pandas, so I can't explain it. Knowing pandas code is useless if you don't know `iloc`

Comment: I have tried the first steps from your answer but it shows ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: I don't think you can solve your problem by asking question. You should study Pandas first before asking questions. read page about `pivot` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping

Comment: Sorry, but I really want to ask. In my real data, The Label Columns has a several value for each id. When I see the documentary, the example show it should have same value for the column. In my case is 'Label' :(

Comment: ok i'm sorry :(